# Can NuGet install the source of a binary alongside so the reference can be debugged?

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, nuget, nuget-package

I am not very familiar with NuGet and I am wondering if NuGet offers a similar feature to Maven where I can choose to not only install the binary of a dependency but also its source code and documentation.

So, when debugging my solution, I can follow the debugger into code running within a dependency declared and managed with NuGet. This would also have the advantage that when the binary package is updated, NuGet would pull the matching source code.

Answer (score 1):

NuGet supports [symbol packages](https://docs.nuget.org/create/creating-and-publishing-a-symbol-package) which allow you to debug into a NuGet package's source code in Visual Studio.

However this only works if the creator of the NuGet package published a symbol package.

Comment: Thanks. That's basically the answer to my question. Unfortunately, it seems to be very rare that Open Source packages actually use this to also distribute their source along the binary for a package version.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is supported. Here is the relevant documentation:

[Creating and Publishing a Symbol Package](https://docs.nuget.org/create/creating-and-publishing-a-symbol-package)

Here is an example of our NuSpec-File. It ist so generic, that it's literally the same for every package:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<package >
    <metadata>
        <id>$id$</id>
        <title>$title$</title>
        <tags>$tags$</tags>
        <owners>$owners$</owners>
        <authors>$authors$</authors>
        <version>$version$</version>
        <description>$description$</description>
        <copyright>$copyright$</copyright>
        <requireLicenseAcceptance>$requireLicenseAcceptance$</requireLicenseAcceptance>
        <releaseNotes>$releaseNotes$</releaseNotes>
    </metadata>
    <files>
        <file src="readme.txt" />
        <file src="\bin\Release\*.pdb" target="lib\net45" />
        <file src="**\*.cs" target="src" exclude="obj\**"/>
        <file src="**\*.vb" target="src" exclude="obj\**"/>         
    </files>
</package>
```

We also use the Visual Studio Extension "NuGet Deploy", you can find it in the VS Gallery.

If you still cannot Step into your package source code, **make sure you loaded the symbols**. Check it during dubugging in the Pane "DEBUG->Windows->Modules"